# vk.com getting token always gives access_token has expired

Tags: python, vk

I'm testing the vk.com api to be able to perform a search.
I can get the token, but when I use it, it always returns the error: "access_token has expired"
Please can you give me a hand to see if the code is wrong, or is it a vk configuration?

Thank you very much

```
import vk
import requests

url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=myClient&client_secret=mySecret&v=5.65&grant_type=client_credentials'
request = requests.get(url).json()
access_token = request["access_token"]

session = vk.Session(access_token)
api = vk.API(session)
search = api.search.getHints(q='python')
```

The error:

```
File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vk\api.py", line 173, in __call__
    return self._api._session.make_request(self)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vk\api.py", line 102, in make_request
    raise error
vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 28. Application authorization failed: access_token has expired.. request_params = {'oauth': '1', 'method': 'search.getHints', 'q': 'python'}
```

Comment: read more about [this API method](https://vk.com/dev/search.getHints): you should grant access to **friends and groups**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we can manually obtain token following URL

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=SCOPE&response_type=token&v=5.65

where

- `APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID` is one of your applications ID, full list of managed applications can be found [here](https://vk.com/apps?act=manage)
- `SCOPE` is a list of comma separated [permissions](https://vk.com/dev/permissions)

if we take a look at documentation about [`search.getHints` method](https://vk.com/dev/search.getHints) we will find out that

> This method can be called with a user token received in Standalone-app via Implicit Flow. Access rights required: **friends and groups**.

so our `SCOPE` may be like `friends,groups` (also we can add `offline` permission to make "eternal" token, but it is not safe)

So our URL for generating token to application with id = `1` may look like

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=1&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends,groups&response_type=token&v=5.65

after following this link there will be form like

[image: accessing request from application]

we must check that it is our application and click `Allow`, after that we will be redirected and token will be in redirected page URL from which we can finally get our token:

[image: redirect]